# KerasRegression Loss is too large

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, model, data-science

everyoe, i'm new to Keras, deep learning and stuff, i got a problem here, which when i fit the model, the loss is just to far, and too big. the lost probably should outcome at least not more than 100K, but comes more than 300.000K. I don't know where is the problem, here is my model and code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split,KFold,cross_val_score
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error,mean_absolute_error,explained_variance_score

data = pd.read_excel('dataset_real.xlsx')
data_real = data.drop(["no","bulan","tahun","kota","kecamatan/wilayah","korban_hilang"],axis=1)
X = data_real.drop(["taksiran_kerugian"],axis=1)
y = data_real["taksiran_kerugian"]
minmax = MinMaxScaler()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)
X_train_scaled = minmax.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = minmax.transform(X_test)

def model_kebakaran():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(10,input_dim=10,activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(1))
  model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_error",optimizer="adam")
  return model

seed = 5
np.random.seed(5)
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model_kebakaran,nb_epoch=500,batch_size=5,verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10,random_state=seed)
result = cross_val_score(estimator,X_train_scaled,y_train.values,cv=kfold,n_jobs=1)

print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (result.mean(), result.std())) #Results: -308763363.20 (114215884.15) MSE
```

and when i try to predict a value, what it should be is

```
y_test.iloc[50] #350000000
```

but here's the prediction

```
test = X_test.iloc[10].values
test = test.reshape(-1,10)
prediction = estimator.predict(X_test)
prediction[50] #7.092292
```

Here is the
[X_train](https://ibb.co/jzsdSqm)
Here is the
[y_train](https://ibb.co/r3gnvhD)

Answer (score 0):

When you use your `X_test` data to make the prediction you should use the `X_test_scaled` data instead because the model was trained on the scaled data.

If you provide X_test samples as input to `predict`, you are asking the model to make a prediction in an input range it has not seem before.

So try:

```
test = X_test_scaled.iloc[50].values
test = test.reshape(-1,10)
prediction = estimator.predict(test)
prediction[50]
```